# Where is the new value created from the for loop stored?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, python-3.x

I am trying to get my head around the following function and for loop:

```
def invest(amount, rate, time):
    print ("Principal amount: ${}" .format(amount))
    print ("Annual rate of return: {}" .format(rate))
    for t in range(1, 9):
        amount = amount * (1 + rate)
        print ("Year {}: ${}" .format(t, amount))

invest(100, .05, 8)
invest(2000, 0.025, 5)
```

As I understand it the amount of 100 is passed into the function and the for loop calculated the rate of return. This increases the value of the amount to 105.0. However, what I am struggling to understand is where this amount is stored? Is it stored in the function or within the for loop? On the second loop the amount of 105.0 is used, but where does it take this figure from?

A second code example of a similar issue is with the following:

```
def doubles(number):    
    number = number * 2 
    return number       

my_num = 3          
for n in range(0, 3):   
    my_num = doubles(my_num)     
    print (my_num)
```

The for loop takes the number 3 from the my_num variable and passes it to the function which mulitplies it by 2. The number is returned and printed in the for loop. On the second loop it takes the number 6 and passes it to the function. Where is the value of 6 stored? Has it updated the variable, is it held in the for loop or the function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a function is called, python creates a "local scope" (a dict), and that's where the variables are stored. This scope is recreated every time the function is called. The first step is to add the function parameters to locals and then other variables are added as they are used. You can `print(locals()["amount"])` at any time to see what's happening. Once you are in the local function scope, variables go into the same scope regardless of how deeply conditionals are nested. This code keeps reassigning `amount` so it uses the new value each time around the loop.

Answer (score 0):

An assignment like this

```
amount = amount * (1 + rate)
```

means the following: Calculate the result of the right hand side, which happens to involve the value of the variable **amount**. When the computation is done, the result gets stored in the variable on the left hand side. This happens to be **amount**. All in all, **amount** has been updated based on its previous value. The new value is stored in **amount** and the original value is simply overwritten.

Whether this is inside a loop or not does not matter.

Bonus: An expression like **amount = amount * (1 + rate)** does not look pleasing to the eye if you come from a math background, as this sort of expression is simply nonsense in mathematics. To fix this, Python provides a more elegant (but completely equivalent) syntax:

```
amount *= 1 + rate
```

which means "update **amount** by multiplying it by the right hand side".